# How to take a screenshot when a test is failed in JUnit5

Tags: java, selenium, junit5, allure, parallel-testing

I am trying to write functionality that will take a screenshot of my browser in case a test fails. What I care about:

- *take a screenshot and add it to the Allure2 report.*
- *tests must be run in parallel.*
- *information about Tear down in report*

[image: Allure report with tear down]

I tried to use JUnit API to implement **Test Watcher**. I have such a problem with it that when it passes a Driver to the testFailed method (just to do SS in the case of test failed) then, I can't use the **@AfterEach** annotation with closing the Driver because otherwise, the Driver will be **NULL**.

The *BaseTest class* from which the tests inherit contains annotations from JUnit5 and initializes the Driver here, and I would like to shut it down here. The class is also extended by *CustomTestWatcher class* which implements Test Watcher

```
@ExtendWith(CustomTestWatcher.class)
public class TestBase {

protected WebDriver driver;

@BeforeAll
public static void beforeAll() {
    AllureFeatures.generateEnvironmentVariablesForAllure(); // generate enviroments.xml for allure report purposes
}

@BeforeEach
public void setupDriver() {
    WebDriverThreadLocal.setDriver();
    this.driver = WebDriverThreadLocal.getDriver();
    driver.get(BASE_URL);
}

@AfterEach
public void closeDriver() {
    WebDriverThreadLocal.teardown();
}
```

CustomTestWatcher Class
I don't like this solution. It duplicates the code in 4 places for each test status (disabled, successful, aborted, failed). I would prefer to use @AfterEach annotations, unfortunately, I have no idea how... Tear-down will also not be visible on the report.

```
public class CustomTestWatcher implements TestWatcher {
@Override
public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason) {
    WebDriverThreadLocal.teardown();
}
@Override
public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
    WebDriverThreadLocal.teardown();
}
@Override
public void testAborted(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
    WebDriverThreadLocal.teardown();
}
@Override
public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
    ScreenShotCreator.takeScreenShot(WebDriverThreadLocal.getDriver()); // pass the driver and do SS
    WebDriverThreadLocal.teardown();
}
```

I also read that Allure has a TestLifecycleListener interface where you can override the BeforeTestStop method, looks like the perfect place to do SS, just again the question is how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [AfterTestExecutionCallback](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterTestExecutionCallback.html).
and realize your logic inside

```
@Override
  public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    if (context.getExecutionException().isPresent()) {
    takeScreenshot();
    }
}
```